# MediatorLiveData never becomes active when using DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

**Problem**

MediatorLiveData bind to layout using DataBinding never becomes active thus its sources changes are not accounted for

**What I am trying to do**

I am using DataBinding to two-way databind my ViewModel's MediatorLiveData's value to a SeekBars progress as follows:

```
<SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="@{ShaderParameterValue.SEEKBAR_MAX}"
        android:progress="@={parameter.value.basisPoint}"/>
```

The basisPoint field is defined as follows

```
val basisPoint: MediatorLiveData<Int> = object: MediatorLiveData<Int>(){

    override fun setValue(value: Int?) {
        super.setValue(value)
        value?.let { updateCurrentValue(it) }
    }

}.also {
    it.addSource(startValue) { value ->
        calculateBasisPoint(it)
    }
    it.addSource(currentValue) { value ->
        calculateBasisPoint(it)
    }
    calculateBasisPoint(it)
}
```

**What I have found out**

I am adding two sources, but as the LiveData never becomes active as verified by debugger, `calculateBasisPoint` is never called.

When I add my own observer (below) elsewhere to the basisPoint field, the code works as expected.

```
 it.value.basisPoint.observe(this@GLActivity, Observer {
      Log.d(TAG, "basisPoint " + it)
 });
```

The DataBinding also correctly updates the basisPoint when the SeekBar value changes.

Shouldn't the DataBinding mark the MediatorLiveData as active? Is this a bug, or is there something I am misunderstanding here?

I am not sure where can I find the DataBinding source for SeekBar binding to verify the logic, however I would assume it should use the LiveData's observe as usual, so I don't see what could go wrong here.

Comment: I am implementing a seekbar that given a a value should seek between range value / 10 to value * 10, using MediatorLiveData seemed the sanest way to do this, as the SeekBar can only work in integers, and the needed range is in double, also SeekBar min is only supported by some newer sdk version. Thanks for the link!

Comment: They are updated from main thread on button press, I just load a map using GSON, then match them to livedata and update them. I've made sure the matched livedatas are correct, and that the problem lays in the fact that MediatorLiveData never becomes active

Comment: What is the databinding doing, if not observing it?